# Scanning an android device for programs that needs internet connection

Tags: android, permissions

I am trying to implement an application that will scan android device for installed programs that needs internet permission and then disable any of them with a password.

I have tried to research on this but nothing so far.

Please anyone with an idea of how I can do this betterstill a code that can enable accomplish this? I will so much appreciate it.

Comment: thanks rekire for the edited tags.any suggestion to the question?

Comment: I highly doubt, you can "disable" them and enforce a password. Unless you are targetting rooted phones?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the list of packages that requires certain permissions using PackageManager:

```
 PackageInfo pkgInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    packageName, 
                    PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS
                  );
 PermissionInfo[] permissions = pkgInfo.permissions;
```

Comment: and also with packageManager you can get a list of all packages

Comment: @net_whiz: help back if it helped ;) tick it as the correct answer